# Seagate 2TB Hard Disk not recognized

Tags: external-hard-drive

I was recently using my seagate hard disk and suddenly it stops appearing in my computer. Even the light is not appearing, but I can hear the disk spin with a beep sound. It is also recognized in Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers. Is there any way to fix the hard drive?

Comment: You hear the disk spin with a beep sound? That is a bad hard drive.

Comment: I had this exact same thing happen with a Seagate a little over a year ago and it died ridiculously quickly afterward. I would suggest you try to make your best effort to get read access to the drive and, if successful, make a backup of all your data ASAP (like, immediately).

Comment: Agreed with the comment above. It's dead or dying.